# Xcode and Cocos2d project with link error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

When I am trying to build my project after cleaning it, I see following error in linking phase of the build process

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

Can somebody help pls.

Comment: check your apps build settings for anything that says linker or -Xlinker